# How to Move the code from blade to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a table like this Activites Table:
[image]

and i extract the data from the database to the table with this code
in Controller :

```
$TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
    ->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
    ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->select(
       'users.name as name',
       'group_user.user_id as id',
       'groups.name as groupname'
       )
    ->get();
    $view->with('TableB1',$TableB1);
    return $view;
```

In index.blade.php

```
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Team</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>No. of Showing</th>
       <th>No. of Follow up</th>
       <th>New Lead</th>
       <th>Personal Lead</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <?php
     use Carbon\Carbon;
     foreach ($TableB1 as $data){
        echo
            '<tr>
             <th scope="row">'. $data->groupname .'</th>
             <th scope="row">'. $data->name .'</th>';
             // To extract the number of meetings done by each agent(owned_by_id) everyday   
             $meetings = \DB::table('meetings')
                       ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $data->id)
                       ->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->day);
              echo '<th scope="row">' . $meetings->count() . '</th>';
              // To extract the number of calls done by each agent(owned_by_id) everyday   
              $calls = \DB::table('calls')
                     ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $data->id)
                     ->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->day);
              echo '<th scope="row">' . $calls->count() . '</th>';
              // To extract the number of leads created by each agent(owned_by_id) everyday   
              $leads = \DB::table('leads')
                     ->where('lead_status_id', 1)->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $data->id)
                     ->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->day);
              echo '<th scope="row">' . $leads->count() . '</th>';
     }
  ?>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How to move the code in the php blade to the controller?
the code works but I think the code should be in the controller right ?
and if possible is there is a way to filter this data in the table by Month & year through AJAX so i don't have to refresh the page ?

I'm using Laravel 5.7

Comment: your all the queries should be in controller.

Comment: I know but i want to use the foreach loop in the blade i couldn't loop through the data and display them in the table

Comment: you can do by using joining of tables or using relation method.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you could do something like this:

```
// $TableB1 = ...

// note the & in &$entry.
// The & makes $entry writable in the loop (to say it simply)

foreach ($TableB1 as &$entry){
    $entry->meetingCount = (
        \DB::table('meetings')
        ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $data->id)
        ->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->day)
    )->count();

    // $entry->callCount = ...
    // $entry->leadCount = ...
}

// $view->with('TableB1',$TableB1);
```

This loop here could probably be avoided by directly including all the counts in your SQL, but anyway let's continue.

Now you can simply do this in your view:

```
'<tr>
     <th scope="row">'. $data->groupname .'</th>
     <th scope="row">'. $data->name .'</th>';
     <th scope="row">'. $data->meetingCount .'</th>';
     <th scope="row">'. $data->leadCount .'</th>';
    ...
```

Bonus: Since you use Laravel and Blade, why not use its Syntax?

```
<tbody>
@foreach($table as $entry)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$entry->groupname}}</th>
        <th scope="row">{{$entry->name}}</th>
        <th scope="row">{{$entry->meetingCount}}</th>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

No need for `<?php` statements and lots of quote signs.

Comment: i did your code but i got this error https://ibb.co/L5NgnQW
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: How to directly include all counts in my SQL?

Comment: For the error, just use the same code you used in your template too.
`$meetings = \DB::table('meetings')
                       ->where('company_id', 1)->where('owned_by_id', $data->id)
                       ->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->day);` and then `$entry->meetingCount = $meetings->count();`